# isClone() not working as expected

Tags: apex, clone

```
Account acc = new account(name='Rahul');
insert acc;
account acc1 = acc.clone();
insert acc1;
Account accc = [select id from account where id =: acc1.id];
system.debug(accc.isClone());//Supposed to display true
```

But it is being displayed as False.
It is supposed to show true as acc1(accc) is a clone of acc.

Comment: The `isClone()` method will only return true for SObject that are clones in memory. So because `accc` is an actual record, loaded from the database, `isClone()` will return false. If you need this functionality, you will have to keep track of the fact that a record is cloned using a custom field and, for instance, a workflow (see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316690&type=1&mode=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `isClone` is to validate records in memory, not in the database.

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Acme');
insert acc;

Account clonedInMemoryAccount = acc.clone();

// Test before committing to DB
System.assertEquals(true, clonedInMemoryAccount.isClone());

insert clonedInMemoryAccount;

Account databaseAccount = [
    select id
    from Account
    where id = :clonedInMemoryAccount.Id];

System.assertEquals(false, databaseAccount.isClone());
```

In this scenario you can see the difference in the two `assertions` and how you should expect to use `isClone` from the [SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).